# How to update WPF window viewmodel property from view and from model in MVVM light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

My application have some working modes which can be changed from model, and from UI by user. 
When I start the application it show default mode correct (data updated from Model). But as I change selected item from UI, it shows selected item for a while, then unselect it (update from UI, and after that update from model). 
I have devided update logic in two cases 
first, update from UI shall call model update.
second, update UI from model shall not call model update.
What is my mistake?
See code below

View

```
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AlgorithmCollection}" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAlgorithm, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Style="{StaticResource AutoOpenComboBoxStyle}" />
```

ViewModel

```
        private NamedInt _selectedAlgorithm;
        private ObservableCollection<NamedInt> _algorithmCollection;
        public NamedInt SelectedAlgorithm
    {
        get { return this._selectedAlgorithm; }
        set { Set(() => SelectedAlgorithm, ref this._selectedAlgorithm, value);

            if (this._needUpdate && Core.Kernel.Instance.PluginController.ActiveConverter != null &&
                this._selectedAlgorithm != null)
            {
                Core.Kernel.Instance.PluginController.ActiveConverter.SetActiveAlgorithm(this._selectedAlgorithm.Id);
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<NamedInt> AlgorithmCollection
    {
        get { return this._algorithmCollection; }
        set { Set(() => AlgorithmCollection, ref this._algorithmCollection, value);
        }
    }
```

and i listen to model event to update ViewModel when it's nessesary. In constructor of ViewModel

```
            Messenger.Default.Register<SoftwareSettingsUpdateMessage>(this, ReceiveUpdateMessage);



        private void ReceiveUpdateMessage(SoftwareSettingsUpdateMessage action)
    {
        if (action.SettingType.HasFlag(SoftwareSettingsType.Algorithm))
        {
            RefreshAlgorithms();
        }

        this._needUpdate = true;
    }

    private void RefreshAlgorithms()
    {
        var converter = Core.Kernel.Instance.PluginController.ActiveConverter;

        var algorithms = converter?.Algorithms;
        if (algorithms != null)
        {
            AlgorithmCollection = new ObservableCollection<NamedInt>(
                algorithms.Select((x, index) => new NamedInt(x, index))
            );

            var activeId = converter.ActiveAlgorithmId;
            if (activeId >= 0 && activeId < AlgorithmCollection.Count)
            {
                this._needUpdate = false;
                SelectedAlgorithm = AlgorithmCollection[activeId];
                this._needUpdate = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SelectedAlgorithm = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AlgorithmCollection = new ObservableCollection<NamedInt>();
            SelectedAlgorithm = null;
        }

        IsActive = true;
    }
```